# How to reset hook position

Tags: modifiers, objects

[image: How can I set the hook object back to rest position?]

The image above shows a simple hook modifier setup with the hook object (the empty) moved. At the end of the line there is a small black dot denoting the rest position of the object. How can I get the empty back there?

Note: The options "reset" and "recenter" both don't accomplish what I want. Reset will put the object back into it's original state without moving the hook. Recenter will put the origin of the hook to the 3D cursor, but once again not move it.

Why do I want this? Well, I have an object rigged with hooks that has already been transformed and don't want to change the rig by changing the rest positions of the hooks. It seems like the rest positions are not centered around the hooked vertices so selecting the geometry and placing the hook there is not an option :(

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to get the position of the hook centre. I looked into the source and unfortunately the variable `HookModifierData { .. float cent[3]; .. ` for the hook centre is not exposed as a RNA property. My guess is that it is not yet possible without a very minor patch to blenders source code. Actually just 4 lines of code will do the trick. Ill probably provide a patch to the blender tracker.

Comment: Diff available here [https://developer.blender.org/D529](https://developer.blender.org/D529).

Comment: Wow, applied the patch and I can clear the hook location using Python :) Thank you!

Comment: Cool, can't guarantee the patch gets into trunk though. Might be best to poke one of the core devs first. Regarding your question on the tracker.. have a look at trunk/blender/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators. You would need to add a new file(module) and add the name to `__init__.py`'s `_modules`.

Comment: I changed the patch by @user2859 by adding an operator that resets the hook's position back to it's center: https://developer.blender.org/D530

Comment: The patch has been applied by Campo and will be part of Blender 2.72 - thank you again for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Empties have no rest position. It is privilege of bones. 
Bones can be used as Hooks targets. 
All you have to do is replacing empties in your rig by bones and use them in pose mode.

Answer (score 0):

Smiple:

(<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>)

This works since the *"Black Dot"* shows the location of the empty with out any transforms.

It is also worth noting that if you hit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>), location it will jump back.

Comment: Tried it, neither is working :( Empty jumps back to scene origin...